# [Firestore.instance.settings(timestampsInSnapshotsEnabled: true)]=> Here "timestampsInSnapshotsEnabled" is not working or not available

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Describe the bug:
I am using the version cloud_firestore-0.13.4+2 , for the project and i want add the Firestore settings for that i was adding it to Main.dart in **void main() async{Firestore.instance.settings(timestampsInSnapshotsEnabled: true)} ** but it not accepted here, any solution...?

To Reproduce:
Steps to reproduce the behavior:

```
install Library cloud_firestore - 0.13.4+2
Add the lines in main.dart as in screenshot
u won't see that "timestampsInSnapshotsEnabled" is available
```

Expected behavior:
It must accept the "timestampsInSnapshotsEnabled", if not how to do :{

Answer (score 0):

```
Firestore.instance.settings(timestampsInSnapshotsEnabled: true)
```

It is depreciate or removed by flutter team as you can see in [changelogs](https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore/changelog)
Now settings wont accept any paremeter